# error when trying to call an index from a list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have a huge list and I'm trying to make a function that will print the data_sets[51] which is:

```
['X', ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet B', 'Location 2', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet C', 'Location 3', 'Upright'],
          ['Sheet D', 'Location 4', 'Upright']],
```

this line if the 51st list inside the first lot of lists

This is my code which is has all the function above it drawing the sheets

```
def paste_up(position):

    for position in data_sets:
        #start location
        if position[1] == "Location 1":
            start_position = (-300, 0)
        elif position[1] == "Location 2":
            start_position = (-100, 0)
        elif position[1] == "Location 3":
            start_position = (100, 0)
        elif position[1] == "Location 4":
            start_position = (300, 0)

        #start direction
        if position[2] == "Upright":
            start_direction = (90)
        elif position[2] == "Upside down":
            start_direction = (270)

        #draw sheet
        if position[0] == "Sheet A":
            draw_sheetA(start_position, start_direction)
        if position[0] == "Sheet B":
            draw_sheetB(start_position, start_direction)
        if position[0] == "Sheet C":
            draw_sheetC(start_position, start_direction)
        if position[0] == "Sheet D":
            draw_sheetD(start_position, start_direction)

paste_up(data_sets[51])
```

But I am getting this error and I am not sure why, I've tried to change the indexes or use [51][1] but it isn't changing the outcome

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/chalysefoster/Documents/2017/QUT Semester 2/IFB104 Building IT Systems/Assigment 1/billboard.py", line 911, in <module>
    paste_up(data_sets[51])
  File "/Users/chalysefoster/Documents/2017/QUT Semester 2/IFB104 Building IT Systems/Assigment 1/billboard.py", line 883, in paste_up
    if position[1] == "Location 1":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thankyou

Comment: Will you at most have three values sent to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see - you recieving IndexError because first element in provided list contains only one element with index 0 ( obviosuly ), so when you try to access el[1] - IndexError raised.

```
>>>for i, element in enumerate(data_sets):
    print(i, element)

0 X
1 ['Sheet A', 'Location 1', 'Upright']
2 ['Sheet B', 'Location 2', 'Upright']
3 ['Sheet C', 'Location 3', 'Upright']
4 ['Sheet D', 'Location 4', 'Upright']
```

I think that's clear for understanding why you get IndexError.

Just add something like this right after you begin itterating your data set:

```
if len(item) != 3 and not isinstance(item, list):
    # continue or raise ValueError ( for example )
    continue
```

BTW, using dictionaries is more clear solution than multiple if-elif statements:

```
def paste_up(data):

    sheets = {
        "Sheet A": draw_sheetA,
        "Sheet B": draw_sheetB,
        "Sheet C": draw_sheetC,
        "Sheet D": draw_sheetD
    }

    locations = {
        "Location 1": (-300, 0),
        "Location 2": (-100, 0),
        "Location 3": (100, 0),
        "Location 4": (300, 0)
    }

    directions = {
        "Upright": (90),
        "Upside down": (270)
    }

    for item in data:

        if len(item) != 3 and not isinstance(item, list):
            # continue or raise ValueError ( for example )
            continue

        # retrieve data
        sheet, location, direction = item

        # get link to fucntion from dictionary
        draw_action = sheets[sheet]

        # get start position from dictionary
        start_position = locations[location]

        # get start direction from dictionary
        start_direction = directions[direction]

        # exec function with found args
        draw_action(start_position, start_direction)
```

Comment: but I need to be able to get the index for the part that has sheet, location and upside down/upright, is that what you mean?

Comment: when I input this with my coding it returns 'none'

Comment: sorry, my bad, didnt replaced `position` variable with `item`

Comment: i've realised that in your example you shadowing variables. Updated my answer with full function

Comment: thank you the sheets are printing now, there's a problem with some of the directions but I think that may be in my earlier coding. thanks for your help, it was great